# Questions that are closed as not a real question should not penalize downvoters of said question

Tags: feature-request, reputation, down-votes, closed-questions

I apologize if this has been suggested already; I have found many similar posts but none dealing with this case;
If a user downvotes a question due to lack of quality or not a real question; and the question is eventually deleted or closed, should the person who downvoted it still receive the -1 rep?

My opinion here is **no** they should not. The question was correctly downvoted and the community agreed; so much in fact they removed/closed the question.

I understand why downvoting costs rep, however in these specific cases I think it is understood that the downvoting was justified and helpful to the community (when i'm editing and voting on questions I generally am drawn towards the [-12] questions first.. kinda like looking at a car accident.)

So again;
Why does downvoting a question that is eventually closed/deleted due to lack of information or not a real question still effect your rep?

Comment: Downvoting questions costs zero rep.

Comment: Downvoting a question *never* affects your rep, deleted or not. Try it.

Comment: Aww WTF - Then there was a bug here - we can close this.

Comment: I had downvoted a Question - Checked my repp and had a -1 for it.. just checked now and it's not on my rep page anymore and my rep is back up... i'll delete this Question and try to get a repo to log as a bug

Comment: You used to lose rep, not anymore.  This was changed recently (a few months I think).

Comment: OK Everyone, no need to downvote me i've already flagged my own question for deletion. I have found a bug, working on steps to repo.

Comment: Or be jerks.. I would delete it if I could.

Comment: @rlemon: Try not to take it personally. One of my first posts on meta was heavily downvoted after I wanted to delete it. Just remember that votes on meta don't mean much: usually just that people disagree, not that they think your post was low-quality.

Comment: @rlemon don't take it too personally :) Its an honest question. Remember you can always ask in Chat too http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta

Comment: It's not even the rep that I care about.. It just shows a lot about the *average user* on the community; when a person states "I cannot delete the question otherwise I would, Please stop downvoting" then receives a slue of downvotes... reminds me of gradeschool.

Answer (score 2):

Downvoting questions is free. Only downvoting an answer costs -1 reputation. If a question is poor, the only one losing rep here will be the original poster, since they made a poor question.

Answer (score 2):

Downvoting questions currently costs zero reputation.

https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

> The primary way to gain reputation is by posting good questions and
>   useful answers. Your peers will vote on your posts, and those votes
>   will cause you to gain (or, in rare cases, lose) reputation:
>
> answer is voted up     +10
>
> question is voted up   +5
>
> answer is accepted     +15 (+2 to acceptor)
>
> question is voted down     -2 (NOTICE NO "-1 to voter" HERE)
>
> answer is voted down   -2 (-1 to voter)

Comment: I do think i've found a bug. I did downvote a question and saw a -1 in my rep tab on my profile page.. After posting the question and seeing your responses I went to grab a screenshot of it and it was gone (also my 1 rep point had been returned).. i'm working to see if I can get steps to repo but so far nothing. *and I was not mistaken in seeing it. It struck me as so odd that it would function that way I came here and posted!*

Comment: It could have been an old cached page that just coincidentally had a -1 from a prior downvote on an answer.

Comment: no, same question... no answers posted to it before it was closed. so I can't see the possibility that I down-voted an answer to the question. and for the same day (it was today) I no longer have a -1...

Comment: The bottom line is the *glitch* was nothing more than a glitch (my end or SO doesn't matter), and I had asked on the chat whether or not this was the case and no one offered up the information that down-voting a question is free. So I posted it here thinking it was ill-conceived functionality. I'm still trying to figure out what went wrong.. now i'm just left with a sour taste because of all of the down-votes. My question was not bad, it was misinformed. My Q. was clear and concise with my problem, and I showed 'research' by searching other questions... granted I should have read the FAQ..

Comment: I don't want to start a discussion. this post is closed... just had  to get my 2 cents out.

Comment: @rlemon Understandable, hope you are able to get it all figured out.  Good luck.  btw, If it makes you feel any better, my first question here on meta had -6 before I deleted it =).